# Set an array to zero with c++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I simply want to set a complete array back to 0. Something like a "reset" method. 
I know that I can use something like this to initalize an array to zero:

```
int array[100] = {0};     //possible since c++11
```

but I am not sure to reset it. Something like `array[100] = {0};` only sets the 100-element to 0. I know I can do it with a for loop, but there has to be a better way. 
I am not allowed to use memset cause of the coding guideline.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: "Something like array[100] = {0}; only sets the 100-element to 0" no it is not, that's UB it can do anything.

Comment: The example you give is actually original C, and in original C there is very little help for arrays, except memset.
Would it be acceptable to wrap a template round your memset?

Comment: @GemTaylor Sadly it is not. Realy? I thought that the array initalization is part since c++11 and not possible in c. I might be wrong here.

Comment: for reference, anti-dupe: [Reset C int array to zero : the fastest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146395/reset-c-int-array-to-zero-the-fastest-way)

Comment: `std::array` is your friend. It's a safer array. It's just a normal built-in array underneath so there's no memory allocation overhead.

Comment: _I am not allowed to use memset cause of the coding guideline._ but that guideline allows you to use simple arrays? It doesn't tell you what to use instead of memeset?

Comment: @manni66 Correct and correct. In some projects you get predefined datatypes like "myint16", shit operators for those types, no std support and tons of restrictions. Everyday life of a programmer and I cant change it.

Comment: @CodingCat no, not everyday life of a programmer. Or, to speak with Andrei Alexandrescu: call your headhunter.

Comment: C++11 brought in the ability to use C-style initialisation on C++ objects. C already had `char strArray[] = "Hello world";` since the 70s!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);
```

Answer (score 25):

For a C style array such as `int array[100]` you can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) as long as `array` is an array. A pointer to the array will not work.

```
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);
```

If you are using a pointer to the first element, you must supply the size of your array yourself.

```
std::fill(array, array + size, 0);
```

In C++, it's recommended to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C style arrays. For example, you could use `std::array<int, 100> foo;` instead of `int foo[100];` `std::array` always knows its size, doesn't implicitly decay to a pointer and has value semantics. By using `std::array` you can simply reset the array with :

```
foo.fill(0);
```

or

```
foo = {};
```

Comment: How do you know the default value assigned by `foo = {}`?

Comment: @Phlucious That's [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). If the list is empty or shorter than the number of elements, the remaining elements are  [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). For `int` type elements, that means initializing them to zero.

Comment: If you want to create an `std::array` initialized to zero you can create the array as
```c++
std::array<int, 100> row({0});
```
because the object in its construction calls `std::fill_n`, that for C++20, I don't know for previous standards.